# Header message not showing

Tags: php, http, messagebox

I'm trying to implement [this cookie based voting system on my website](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/04/voting-system-with-jquery-php) and can't make it work correctly.

The fact is that  `header('HTTP/1.1 500 Already Voted this Content!');`

is working on local (it show "Already Voted this Content!") but once online it doesn't work, I get "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Check your PHP error log.

Answer (score 0):

add this code at the begin of your php file for debug:

```
ini_set('display_errors','1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: I tried this, but nothing changed. In Firebug i got : "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error" when i'm on local and "NetworkError: 500 Already Voted" online

Comment: maybe the 500 response is replaced by apache's Custom Error Responses setting

Comment: if u r behind a proxy, some proxy will skip the custom 500 msg

Comment: Ok ui tried but nothing worked, but i modificated the script and it now works, thanks for the help.